# c++ Reading doubles from file, but recording if program encounters a string

Tags: c++, fstream

Ok, so my code all works fine but there's a small problem, I have an input file that I want to read from and sometimes a number is replaced by a letter. The file might look like this:

```
3.5
45.8
gh
67.34
39.5
sj
4.73
```

I want to know that there were two numbers missing after I'd read in all the values. At the moment my code just ignores them as if they weren't there. I tried this:

```
double line;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while (myfile >> line) {
    if (myfile.fail()) {
        cout << "Error, line is not a number." << endl;
        j = j + 1;
    }
    mydata[i] = line;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

but the code doesn't ever print the error message! Why not? Thank you.
(`i` counts the numbers, `j` is supposed to count the errors)

Comment: If `fail()` is true after the extraction is performed `(myfile >> line)` the body will never be executed, thus you'll never see the message.

Comment: Read `std::string`s in 1st place and try to convert them to `double` in a 2nd step!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (myfile >> line) 
{
    if (myfile.fail()) 
    {
        cout << "Error, line is not a number." << endl;
        j = j + 1;
    }
    mydata[i] = line;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Your problem is that the first line `while (myfile >> line)` will evaluate to `false` when it gets to the line `gh`, so your conditional gets skipped altogether.  If you are looking to count errors, your code would need to be more like

```
std::string sLine;
while (std::getline(myfile, sLine)) 
{
    std::istringstream iss(sLine);
    if (!(iss >> line))
    {
        cout << "Error, line is not a number." << endl;
        ++j;
    }
    else
    {
        mydata[i] = line;
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh gosh, that's so obvious once you say it. Thanks

Comment: What does `istringstream iss(sLine);` do in the example?

Comment: `sLine` is a `std::string`.  [`std::istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/) allows a `std::string` to be treated as an input stream (so you can extract using `>>` just as you would with `std::cin` or an instance of `std::ifstream`).

Comment: Ah, ok thanks. I've not used that before and my compiler says this:
     `error: variable ‘std::istringstream iss’ has initializer but      incomplete type
        istringstream iss(sLine);`

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to include the header `<sstream>`.